# Capturing the visualization created by D3 Library and storing the state in DB

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I am a newbie to D3 library. The application utilizes D3 library to plot charts. Some of the changes like button click, zoom happens on the fly without hitting the server.

Is there any way to capture the state,store the state in the database and then re-create the exact visualization??

Comment: From what I understand, D3.js only changes the way your data is displayed _client-side_. For you to be able to do this, I imagine you would have to traverse the visualization, get what you need to store and push it to a data structure (ie, your DB). But be aware that you would also have to change the way your data is retrieved to account for this - I can't imagine this being an easy task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D3 charts are scalable vector graphics (SVGs).

The current state of any chart can be captured by selecting the SVG using d3 itself. For example can just call :

```
var allSVGs = d3.selectAll("svg")
```

This call will select all the svg elements on the page. You can then iterate through them and serialize them to xml like so :

```
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
allSVGs.forEach(function(svgElement) {
var svg = d3.select(svgElement).attr("version", 1.1).attr("xmlns",
                "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg").node()
        xmlString = xmlString + serializer.serializeToString(svg);
```

You can then POST the xml to your server and do whatever you like with it such as storing it in a database.

To re-create the chart you can read the xml from the database and pass it to the browser as it is. I've been doing this on the server side with phantomjs (a headless web browser) and its been working well.

Comment: Yes, that will work, but then you will have a "static" page, where interactions will not be possible as it was in the original d3 graph. A way to restore the state and have the interaction can be inspired by @Gilsha ´s answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645587/capturing-saving-the-current-state-of-d3-js-visualization