# Capturing/Saving the current state of d3.js visualization

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm a newbie to D3 and am looking to build a simple art application that allows users to drop d3 data points on a custom background, creating art in the process.

Is it possible to save each D3 node's position after a user drops it, such that when the page is reloaded, all nodes will migrate back to their positions?

Any help here is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not mentioned which d3 layout you use. anyway, just collecting the data bonded to the nodes and links would do the job. Here is the working code snippet.

1) Update the chart.
2) Clear the chart.
3) Load the chart with the updates.

Hope this helps.

```js
var initialData = {
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"Myriel","group":1},
    {"name":"Napoleon","group":1},
    {"name":"Mlle.Baptistine","group":1},
    {"name":"Mme.Magloire","group":1},
    {"name":"CountessdeLo","group":1},
    {"name":"Geborand","group":1},
    {"name":"Champtercier","group":1},
    {"name":"Cravatte","group":1},
    {"name":"Count","group":1}    
  ],
  "links":[
    {"source":1,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":2,"target":0,"value":8},
    {"source":3,"target":0,"value":10},
    {"source":3,"target":2,"value":6},
    {"source":4,"target":0,"value":1}    
  ]
};
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

draw(initialData);
var link, node;
function draw(graph){
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

var drag = force.drag()
    .on("dragstart", dragstart);

  node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(drag);

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });

function dragstart(d) {
  d.x = d3.event.x;
  d.y = d3.event.y;
  d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
}
  }
var savedGraph = { nodes: [], links: [] };
d3.select("#saveBtn").on('click',function(){
  savedGraph.nodes = node.data();
  savedGraph.links = link.data(); 
  svg.selectAll("*").remove();
});
d3.select("#loadBtn").on('click',function(){    
  console.log(savedGraph);
  draw(savedGraph);
});
```

```css
.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Clear" id="saveBtn"/>
<input type="button" value="Load" id="loadBtn"/>
```

Comment: Wow @Gilsha, this is very helpful. Thank you so much. I have a follow-up that came up today while scoping a different, but similar project. Is it possible to drop d3 nodes on a mapbox map and have the data persist. Rather than x,y coordinates, the lat,long would need to be captured. What do you think is the best way to go about doing that?

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a persistence library from D3, so you probably need to persist your with your own way.

If you only care about position, then you just need to create an array of positions, i.e. `var positions = [ { x: x1, y: y1 }, { x: x2, y: y2 }, ... ]`, and you can choose to send this data to server, or persist in browser's local storage if you are fine with only persisting this on the specific browser, e.g.

```
// persist
window.localStorage.setItem('positions',JSON.stringify(positions));

// When the page is loaded
var positions = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('positions'));
```

Then you can use the positions to redraw all the nodes.

Comment: Thank you, @Natural Lam! Very helpful indeed!